# Is there a way to show all docvariables from a word file?

Tags: ms-word, docvariable

I have a Microsoft-Word File which contains several DocVariables.
In our application we fill/replace these DocVariables with content.

With the shortcut Alt+F9 I can switch in a mode in which I can see the DocVariable.

But in the document I have now, there are DocVariable which I cannot see.
Is there a way/mode in Word 2007 in which I can see all the DocVariables which are defined in the Word-File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a way to do this with MS Word's built in features. You could write a custom VBA script that would get a list of all the DocVariables. But even easier than that I use the following program when I need to do what you are saying: http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/cc_var_bm_doc_prop_tools_addin.html

It is a free add-in for Word that has done the job very well the times I used it.